# Data attributes not getting detected by JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I've been trying to pass these data through the data attribute which will then be used by `JQuery`, but for some reason, some of them are undefined when I console log them. As you can see in the picture, only the `$subscription->id` and the `$subscription->tax` variables are getting read by JQuery while the rest are undefined.
[image]

I am using `laravel blade`, and this is the code that is responsible for sending these data over to `JQuery`:

```
                <a 
                  class="btn btn-sm mt-1 btn-light btn-outline-dark col-12" 
                  href="#"
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  data-target="#edit-subscription-modal"
                  data-id="{{$subscription->id}}"
                  data-cId="{{$subscription->customer_id}}"
                  data-uId="{{$subscription->user_id}}"
                  data-pId="{{$subscription->product_id}}"
                  data-sDate="{{$subscription->startDate}}"
                  data-eDate="{{$subscription->endDate}}"
                  data-pTerms="{{$subscription->paymentTerms}}"
                  data-tax="{{$subscription->tax}}"
                  >Edit</a>
```

When I `dd()` the variables on the blade file they do return data, but when I console log them in `JQuery`, they turn out as `undefined`. This is the block of JQuery code:

```
$('#edit-subscription-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var subscriptionId = button.data('id')
        var customerId = button.data('cId')
        var userId = button.data('uId')
        var productId = button.data('pId')
        var startDate = button.data('sDate')
        var endDate = button.data('eDate')
        var paymentTerms = button.data('pTerms')
        var tax = button.data('tax')
        var modal = $(this)
        
        console.log(subscriptionId)
        console.log(customerId)
        console.log(userId)
        console.log(productId)
        console.log(startDate)
        console.log(endDate)
        console.log(paymentTerms)
        console.log(tax)
        
        modal.find('.modal-body #subscription-id').val(subscriptionId)
    })
```

I've tried changing up the names of the `data attributes`, but still no cigar. I hope someone can shed light on this.

Comment: `$('#edit-subscription-modal').on` replace this with `$('.className').on` and add that class to `a` tag

Comment: @KamleshPaul Tried this already too, assigned 'edit-sub-modal' class to the anchor tag and changed `$('#edit-subscription-modal').on` to `$('.edit-sub-modal').on` and it doesn't console.log at all when i do that

Comment: Hi ,check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/uem2jafr/) fiddle this is what you need ?

Comment: @Swati thanks but after trying this, console.log just return all data undefined :(

Comment: But it works in demo code.not sure whats problem then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, it had something to do with the naming of the data attribute in my blade file!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add class to `<a>` tag then listen [click event](https://api.jquery.com/click/) for that class like

```html
<a 
class="btn btn-sm mt-1 btn-light btn-outline-dark col-12 subscription-modal-click" 
href="#"
data-toggle="modal"
data-target="#edit-subscription-modal"
data-id="{{$subscription->id}}"
data-cId="{{$subscription->customer_id}}"
data-uId="{{$subscription->user_id}}"
data-pId="{{$subscription->product_id}}"
data-sDate="{{$subscription->startDate}}"
data-eDate="{{$subscription->endDate}}"
data-pTerms="{{$subscription->paymentTerms}}"
data-tax="{{$subscription->tax}}"
>Edit</a>


<script>
    $('.subscription-modal-click').click(function(){
        var button = $(this) // Button that triggered the modal
        var subscriptionId = button.data('id')
        var customerId = button.data('cId')
        var userId = button.data('uId')
        var productId = button.data('pId')
        var startDate = button.data('sDate')
        var endDate = button.data('eDate')
        var paymentTerms = button.data('pTerms')
        var tax = button.data('tax')
        var modal = $(this)
        
        console.log(subscriptionId)
        console.log(customerId)
        console.log(userId)
        console.log(productId)
        console.log(startDate)
        console.log(endDate)
        console.log(paymentTerms)
        console.log(tax)
        
        modal.find('.modal-body #subscription-id').val(subscriptionId)
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Did it, but it shows the same results. The only data getting transferred and console.logged is the `$subscription->id` and `$subscription->tax`

Comment: @fael_ then data is not coming from database

Comment: it does, when I `dd()` the variables, it shows the data.

Comment: then way half is coming and half is not you need to check `a` tag is all data is appending